# I can not select a link using class spam in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following command in HTML:

```
**<a id="pt1:cb1" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">

<span class="x106">Cadastro de cliente</span>**
```

Must select the page in the "Cadastro de cliente" item.

I used the following command , but it did not work.

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[7]/div/div[6]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/span"));
        menuCadCliente.click();
```

I'm New world of selenium webdriver , so I ask your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the span that you are interested is always going to be a child of the anchor tag with the id "pt1:cb1" then I would suggest using:

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#pt1:cb1 .x106"));
```

otherwise, if there is no guarantee on the order, I would suggest using a logical loop to find the right element.

```
List<WebElement> spans = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".x106"));
WebElement menuCadCliente;
for (WebElement span : spans) {
  if (span.getText().equals("Cadastro de cliente")) {
    menuCadCliente = span;
  }
}
```

or if you could try using :contains, which matches substring.

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span:contains('Cadastro de cliente')"));
```

However, this method would also match span that has text such as Cadastro de clientes1231

Comment: Thank you very much, your help was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

That xpath looks overly complicated. It might be useful to think more simple. You can search by id, but if the id attribute is dynamically generated, you can always try searching it by 'linkText' :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cadastro de cliente")).click();
```

Comment: Above I used the command as follows: WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cadastro de cliente"));
  menuCadCliente.click();

But it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You are using the complete XPath, which almost always is a bad idea. From the little bit of code you posted there are too many solutions. Any one of the following *could* work:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("x106"))
driver.findElement(By.tagName("span"))
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cadastro de cliente"))
```

Have a read through the [documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp).

Comment: It did not work , I used the commands listed and none of them worked . I will post all the code again and if consigue help me .

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet of the page and have the link where I need to click.

```
<div class="xwq" style="position:absolute;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px">
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%">
<div id="pt1:sdi1" class="af_showDetailItem" style="position:absolute;width:auto;height:auto;top:0px;left:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px">
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb1" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Cadastro de cliente</span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb2" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Relacionar cliente à Proposta de Venda</span>
</a>
</div>
<div>
<a id="pt1:cb3" class="xfc p_AFTextOnly" href="#" onclick="return false;">
<span class="x106">Iniciar processo de Análise de Crédito</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Command in selenium was used :

```
WebElement menuCadCliente = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cadastro de cliente"));
menuCadCliente.click();
```

What has been identified is that a single class and inside it has different values ​​. This is my if I have not understood erroado.

Comment: This is not an answer. For additional information please use the edit function of your original post.